# TypeScript Cannot find name `SpeechGrammarList`, which is implemented in "DOM"

Tags: javascript, typescript, webspeech-api

TS Error for `SpeechGrammarList`,
but this is part of the Web Speech API, and the interface is implemented in "DOM". Why is TS still giving this error?

Code:

```
export interface SpeechRecognitionProperties {
    grammars?: SpeechGrammarList; //TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpeechGrammarList'.
    lang?: string;
}
```

`"typescript": "^4.4.4"`

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a TS 4.4 libdom change. See https://github.com/Riley-Brown/react-speech-to-text/issues/23